# Generating C# documentation without building an Xml document

Tags: c#, documentation

First of all, I've seen [Generating Documentation from C# XML Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381/generating-documentation-from-c-xml-comments) and many others like it, but none of the suggested tools work for what I need.

I need a free tool that can generate documentation (preferably in html) from my source code without using the xml document created by Visual Studio. The project has warnings as errors turned on and checking the option to generate that xml file creates hundreds of errors. In effect, this rules out 90% of c# documentation generators, including Sandcastle, NDoc3, Live Documenter, docu, and ImmDoc.

Doxygen almost works, but I can't seem to get it to generate documentation for overloaded generic classes, such as:

```
public class MyClass<Foo>
public class MyClass<Foo, Bar> : MyClass<Foo>
```

MyClass has documentation, but MyClass does not.

So then the question - is there:

1. a documentation generator I haven't seen that can handle this case,
2. a config option in one of the tools I've listed that would make it work without requiring the xml-documentation file,
3. or even a way to turn off **just** the comment compiler warnings without affecting the build warnings?

**Edit.** A solution by way of method #3 is to suppress the following warnings relating to xml comments: 1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1574, 1580, 1581, 1584, 1587, 1589, 1590, 1591, 1592, 1598, 1710, 1711, 1712, 1723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable [warning `1591`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk18c1w9.aspx) in Project Properties, then generate the XML.

Comment: While that does get rid of the majority of the errors, there's several other commenting warnings. For this to be a proper solution, I need to disable all comment-related warnings. [This msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) was helpful in finding the rest of them. Marking as solution for pointing me in the right direction =)

Comment: @GStepanov: You should just fix the other ones.  They are real errors and should not be hard  to fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own the project; if I did, I would have fixed them and not posted this in the first place.