# How can I disable a specific warning for a C# project in VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, suppress-warnings, xml-documentation

I am trying to generate partial XML documentation during my build process for a C# project in VS2012. When I check the XML documentation file option in Project->Properties->Build, I get a build warning for each public member that lacks documentation. Since we compile with warnings as errors, this blocks the build.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402333/generating-c-sharp-documentation-without-building-an-xml-document) suggests getting past this by disabling certain warnings, but I can't figure out how to do that in VS2012! The MSFT documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only goes up to VS2010 and only covers VB. How can I disable these warnings at the project level in C#/VS2012?

Comment: Does this help at all? [Supress warnings VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj715718.aspx)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The warning you're getting has a number (e.g. CS2000), so what you need to do is right-click on the project, go to the `Build` tab, and add that warning to the `Suppress warnings` text box. You can subsequently suppress more than one by separating them with a comma (e.g. CS2000,CS2001).

Comment: make sure to drop the CS prefix, e.g. use 1591 over CS1591

Comment: In VisualStudio 2019 the suppression works both ways: WITH prefix and WITHOUT prefix. So, you can specify "CS2000, CS2001" as well as "2000, 2001"

Answer (score 40):

For the project level go to Project -> Properties -> Build tab

[image]

If you want to disable the warning to some code section, try this :

```
#pragma warning disable XXX,XXX
            //your code 
#pragma warning restore XXX,XXX
```

Read about [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: In my question I explicitly ask for how to disable warnings at the project level. This answer does not seem to apply.

Answer (score 21):

Just add NoWarn block in the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <NoWarn>1998;1999</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can open the project properties and enter comma separated warning numbers you want to suppress into the Suppress Warnings textbox on the Build tab.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the same place as Visual Studio 2010. In the project properties, on the Build tab, called Suppress warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding _ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS to Current Property Pages, Your Project, C/C++, Preprocessor, Preprocessor Definitions