# Using HtmlHelper for opening and closing tags (Visual Studio Html Warning)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm creating a [HtmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for a `<table>` element to encapsulate some attributes setting as follow:

```
public static FootableTable BeginFootableTable(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string classAttribute, 
    bool sorting = true,
    FootableToggleColumn? toggleColumn = null)
{
    return new FootableTable(htmlHelper, classAttribute, sorting, toggleColumn);
}
```

And the `Footable` class has the `Dispose`, to ensure the `<table>` closing:

```
public class FootableTable : IDisposable
{
    private HtmlHelper Helper { get; set; }

    public FootableTable(HtmlHelper helper,
            string className,
            bool sorting,
            FootableToggleColumn? toggleColumn)
    {
            this.Helper = helper;

            StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();

            sbResult.AppendFormat(@"<table class=""{0}""", className);

            if (toggleColumn != null)
            {
                sbResult.AppendFormat(@" data-toggle-column=""{0}""", Convert.ToString(toggleColumn.Value));
            }

            if (sorting)
            {
                sbResult.Append(@" data-sorting=""true""");
            }

            sbResult.Append(">");

            this.Helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(sbResult.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("</table>");
    }
}
```

I can use it in the razor view with no problem, like this:

```
<div id="container-grid">
    @using (Html.BeginFootableTable("table table-striped table-hover footable"))
    {
        <thead>
<tr>
     <td></td>
</tr>
</thead>
}
</div>
```

Everything works fine at the runtime, but Visual Studio keeps showing an warning, at design time, like this:

> Element 'thead' cannot be nested inside element 'div'.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio that the HtmlHelper renders a table and avoid these alert?

Comment: Is this your answer ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088244/how-can-i-disable-a-specific-warning-for-a-c-sharp-project-in-vs2012

Comment: Not really, I don't want to disable this kind of warning, which helps me create well formatted HTML.
I just need the Visual Studio IDE to undertand my HtmlHelper as a `<table>` element, so there will be no warning.