# How to disable showing the green wavy lines in web.config and css file in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

As show in the screenshot, how can I disable showing the wavy lines?

[image]

Comment: That is an extremely tiny screenshot, which doesn't really show what you are talking about.

Comment: @howcheng Hi, sorry for that inconvenience. I've update the screenshot.

Comment: The green wavy lines are Warnings. This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088244/how-can-i-disable-a-specific-warning-for-a-c-sharp-project-in-vs2012) might help you. But you should try and fix them instead of suppress them, because they may comeback and bite you in the butt later on.

Comment: @zgood Hi, I write a custom handler to process a custom XML block in web.config. But somehow, the warnings show up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Productivity Power Tools extension in VS

Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Solution Error Visualizer -> untick "Show squiggles for error items in Solution Explorer"

Comment: This answer is still relevant in VS 2019. Thanks!